# How to limit the number of authenticated users logged in simultaneously?

Tags: users, performance

I'm building a project for a client who asked for:

1. Limit the number of authenticated users logged in simultaneously.
   For example the site won't allow more than 20 users to be logged in
   at the same time. It would tell the user to try again later.
2. The site would also force the users to log out 30 minutes (for
   example) after they logged in so others could use the site. For this
   part, I found the following modules - [Automated Logout](https://drupal.org/project/autologout) and [Session
   expire](https://drupal.org/project/session_expire).

Is there a module for the first part? or should I code a new one?

Comment: help ? anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Session Limit module (https://drupal.org/project/session_limit)? I do not have first hand experience with it but the module pages says "Configure session limiting exclusions by role" which might be what you want. Alternatively, it also has integration with rules, which also might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I actually saw that module earlier. It limits the number of simultaneous sessions per user. For example, if a user log in from computer A, drupal will terminate his session in computer B.
The "Configure session limiting exclusions by role" doesn't do what I need. It configures the session limit per user according to his role.

Comment: If it was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks.